# alternating classes on wp_list_pages

Tags: wp-list-pages, walker

I'm trying to have alternating classes on the list created by wp_list_pages.

Currently I have extended the Walker_page class updating the start_el function as follows:

```
class Sidebar_walker extends Walker_page {

var $alternate = 'background_1';

function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) {
    if ( $depth )
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    else
        $indent = '';

    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

    $alternate = ($alternate != 'background_1') ? 'background_1' : 'background_2';
    $css_class[] = $alternate;

    if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
        $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
        if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
        elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }

    $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

    $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';

    if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
        if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
            $time = $page->post_modified;
        else
            $time = $page->post_date;

        $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
    }
}
}
```

Only background_1 is printing.  how do I get $alternate to actually update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this a complement to toscho's solution.

I believe that ...

```
$this->alternate = ($this->alternate != 'background_1') ? 'background_1' : 'background_2';
$css_class[] = $this->alternate;
```

... will do what you want.

The difference is that toscho's solution, using the `static` keyword, will make that variable static for any instantiation of this walker-- that is, all instances will share the same value. If you instantiate two walkers the second will pick up where the last left off. That may be what you want, or it may not be. Using `$this` will limit it to the one instance of the walker only.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the method `start_el()` is called it starts from scratch and doesn’t know anything about earlier calls. To make it remember earlier states use the `static` keyword:

```
function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) {
    static $alternate = 'background_1';
```

Now the last state of `$alternate` will be kept for all calls.

Comment: That definitely solved the problem of $alternate updating.  Now I have a new problem.  It is not consistently switching between background 1 and 2.  Because I am only printing the children of the current page, is $alternate updating even when something doesn't echo?